# Why pushing undefined to an empty array give 1?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I do

```js
var a = [].push(undefined);
console.log(a);
```

it gives output as `1` even though undefined was pushed to the array. Any idea why?

Comment: `var a=[];a.push(undefined);console.log(a)`

Comment: _The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array._ `undefined` is a valid array element: `[ undefined ].length === 1`. RTFM?

Comment: See `Return value` at JavaScript Array push() Method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: It will be the same if you push `null` too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're testing it the wrong way. `a` is not defined as the array, as I think you suppose it to be. Try this:

```js
var a = []
a.push(undefined);
console.log(a);
```

You are assigning the return value of [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function to variable `a`. `push` returns the length of the array after pushing the current element in context. So, it returns 1 after pushing `undefined` in the array.

Answer (score 3):

its pushing the length of array inside not the elements

example

```
var a = [].push(5,6,7,8);
  console.log(a); //gives 4
```

Answer (score 1):

[Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array, and thats what is stored in `a`

Answer (score 1):

There was no explicit check has been done when assigning a new property to array object. Assigning a new property in the sense, setting 0,1,2..n properties with values, based on the length of the array.

> 8. Repeat, while items is not empty
>
>    - Remove the first element from items and let E be the value of the element.
>    - Let setStatus be Set(O, ToString(len), E, true).
>    - ReturnIfAbrupt(setStatus).
>    - Let len be len+1.

You can see it [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.push). Step 8.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis +1 for that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, because it doesn't mention the return value from the `.push()` method.

Comment: @nnnnnn OP seems to be having knowledge in why push returns 1. I personally assumed it by seeing his reps. But `it gives output as 1 even though undefined was pushed to the array.` this sentence in his question made me to think he wants to know why undefined is getting pushed into the array.

Comment: Oh right. I see what you mean, although I think you made that distinction clearly in your comment but not in the answer. (Although if "undefined **was** pushed" then that means that undefined *is* in the array...)